# The job 'GUID' is already running and cannot be canceled- PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, deployment

A deployment or retraction is already under way for the solution "xxx.wsp", and only one deployment or retraction at a time is supported

it occurs if anomalies deployment is running for the same package in the backend due to some previous deployment has been crashed before for some reason.

To avoid this problem we need do the followings:

- Look for the deploy jobId to break the running by the following
  command:  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
  extensions\12\BIN>stsadm-o enumdeployments
- Cancel the deploy typing the following command:  C:\Program
  Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
  extensions\12\BIN>stsadm-o canceldeployment-id "GUID jobId"

But after execute the second command I got following message
The job 'GUID' is already running and cannot be canceled.

Comment: did you try to restart the SharePoint Admin and SharePoint timer services from the Serivces console on all server in farm?

Comment: Try running "stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs" and then the canceldeployment.